# Javascript string split method not working inside a loop with a & delimeter

Tags: javascript, split

The code:

```
var x = "a&b";
var y = x.split("&");
```

gives y[0] and y[1] as a and b respectively, as it should.

However, when I put the second statement into a loop:

```
var x = "a&b";
for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {
 var y = x.split("&");
}
```

the split() function no longer works properly, giving y[0] as "a&b" and y[1] as undefined. If I instead define x inside the loop as well, then everything works as before. I can actually resolve this issue by using a different delimeter (say, | instead of &), but I am curious to understand what causes the problem in the code above.

Could someone please explain what is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: Well, the second code block works perfectly in my browser.

Comment: Your code works properly

Comment: i am voting to close this question as unable to reproduce it.

Comment: its working correctly check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u98mLkxn/

Comment: Perhaps provide a code snippet that reproduces your error or give some details about the environment you are running this code in.

Comment: Okay, so I guess it's an environment issue then. I hadn't actually checked it in my browser locally, sorry. I ran this code in a Wordpress page hosted on Siteground.